# react native gifted chat caught error while running test cases

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, cucumber

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'SelectableBackground')

  at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@expo/react-native-action-sheet/lib/commonjs/ActionSheet/TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe.tsx:33:43)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@expo/react-native-action-sheet/lib/commonjs/ActionSheet/ActionGroup.js:1:961)
```

I am working in chatbot, and whenever run the test case get error mention below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'SelectableBackground')

  at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@expo/react-native-action-sheet/lib/commonjs/ActionSheet/TouchableNativeFeedbackSafe.tsx:33:43)
  at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@expo/react-native-action-sheet/lib/commonjs/ActionSheet/ActionGroup.js:1:961)
```

Even though, I haven't implement anything in test cases